# How to check SEQ not having '0' records

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table A

```
ID      SEQ 
123      0
123      1
123      2
123      3
234      2
234      4
234      5
345      2
345      3
345      4
```

Now I need to check IDs which don't have SEQ=0. In above example `234` and `345` are dont have `0`

Comment: Can you just check what is min(SEQ)?

Comment: Google and learn about "WHERE NOT EXISTS()"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `NOT EXISTS` clause to filter the IDs:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM TableA a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM TableA b WHERE SEQ = 0 AND a.ID = b.ID)
```

Runnable Sample:

```
CREATE TABLE #TableA ( ID INT, SEQ INT )

INSERT  INTO #TableA
        ( ID, SEQ )
VALUES  ( 123, 0 ),
        ( 123, 1 ),
        ( 123, 2 ),
        ( 123, 3 ),
        ( 234, 2 ),
        ( 234, 4 ),
        ( 234, 5 ),
        ( 345, 2 ),
        ( 345, 3 ),
        ( 345, 4 )

SELECT DISTINCT
        ID
FROM    #TableA a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT ID
                     FROM   #TableA b
                     WHERE  SEQ = 0
                            AND a.ID = b.ID )

DROP TABLE #TableA
```

Produces:

```
ID
===
234
345
```

Answer (score 3):

`select distinct id from table where id not in (select id from table where seq = 0)`

Comment: I like to add `and ID is not null`.  becuase if a record get's added with `{ID:Null, Seq:0}` the query will never reutrn results. [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4bda2/3)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT ID
FROM mytable
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN SEQ = 0 THEN 1 END) = 0
```